# Simulink: How can I use object instances from workspace in an embedded matlab function?

Tags: matlab, simulink

In this case I have a neural network (NN) instance in my base workspace that I wish to use in a simulation with Simulink. I wrapped the use of the NN in an Embedded Matlab function with input arguments that should be used in by the net.

In principal I wish to do something like this:

```
function XBDDprime = NN(F, XB, XBD, XBDD)
%#eml
global net;
XBDDprime = net([F XB XBD XBDD]');
```

Where the goal is to fetch the `net` object from base workspace (which is an instance of the class `network`).

This a swing at the problem where I used `evalin` to read the variable from workspace:

```
function XBDDprime = NN(F, XB, XBD, XBDD)
%#eml
eml.extrinsic('evalin');
net = evalin('base', 'net'); %Fetch net from workspace
XBDDprime = net([F XB XBD XBDD]'); %Error!
```

This doesn't compile because it seems like simulink thinks net is an array and `net(...)` is array subscripting (actual error message: Subscripting into an mxArray is not supported).

It seems to me like Simulink needs to have a full definition of any object used to be able to compile the embedded matlab function, is that correct? Is there even a solution? Can I use `Simulink.Signal` somehow to wrap the NN and add that as an argument to the function block?

### Edit

I tried using `load` as well to load the serialized `net` object from file. That didn't work either. Seems to be the same problem where the compiler thinks `s` is an `mxArray`.

```
function XBDDprime = NN(F, XB, XBD, XBDD)
%#eml
eml.extrinsic('load')
s = load('net');
XBDDprime = s.net([F XB XBD XBDD]');
```

### Solution

I finally caved and went for the matlab function block which can look like any of the examples above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define the `net` parameter as an input of the `NN` function and use a `From Workspace` block to get it into your model. I'm not sure if this will work with an `Embedded MATLAB function` block, you might need to switch to an `M Code` block.

Comment: I tried using `From Workspace` but it seems that it only supports scalar or vector-data of doubles.

Answer (score -2):

Generate Simulink block for neural network simulation 
Syntax
gensim(net,st)
To Get Help
Type help network/gensim.